# How to divide vector to subvectors based on another vector in matlab

Tags: matlab, vector

I have a vector, let it be `b=[1 2 2 3 4 1 2 1 4...]` and another vector `A(n)` which I want to divide in vectors in the following way:

`A(1)` and `A(6)` and `A(8)` will all belong in vector 1 called Av1
`A(2)` and `A(6)` and `A(8)` will all belong in vector 2 called Av2
etc...

The vector b could have numbers from 1:n meaning I can't  write code individually for each Av. Basically each b(i) corresponds to each A(i) and tells me which subvector it will belong to. Anyone has any idea?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Ok... so is it your goal to extract out values of `i` for each `i` in your vector `b`?  For example, your first output would be an array of 3 1s, the next output has an array of 3 2s, etc.... or do you want to extract **the locations** of where each value of `i` is?  It isn't clear in your problem description

Comment: Not 3 1s, my first vector would consist of the contents of A(1),A(6) and A(8)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, I would not recommend you create separate variables for each array... that will simply be unwieldy.  What if you have 100 different values in `b`?  I recommend you use a `cell` array instead where each cell extracts out the corresponding values of `A`.

A simple call to [`arrayfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html) and [`unique`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) will suffice:

```
out = arrayfun(@(x) A(b == x), unique(b), 'uni', 0);
```

What this will do is for each unique value in `b`, we extract out the corresponding locations in `A` that match and put them into a cell array.  Given your small example:

```
b=[1 2 2 3 4 1 2 1 4];
```

.... and `A` is simply:

```
A = 1:numel(b);
```

I declare `A` like this on purpose so it matches the actual corresponding locations of `A` you are extracting... and so `A(i) = i` for `i = 1` up to as many values as we have `b`.

We get this:

```
>> celldisp(out)

out{1} =

     1     6     8



out{2} =

     2     3     7



out{3} =

     4



out{4} =

     5     9
```

You can see that for each cell, we extract out the right values in `A` corresponding to each unique ID found in `b`.

---

If you're not familiar with `arrayfun`, it basically performs a function on each value of an input array.  In our case, what I want to do is specify an array to be all of the unique values in `b`.  For each unique value in `b`, I take a look at where I can find these locations that match, then use logical indexing to extract out the corresponding values in `A`.

`arrayfun` is basically a `for` loop, and so the equivalent `for` loop code will look something like this:

```
unq = unique(b);
out = cell(1,numel(unq));
for idx = 1:numel(unq)
    x = unq(idx);
    out{idx} = A(b == x);
end
```

We first find all of the unique values in `b` and store them in `unq`, create a cell array that has as many cells as there are unique values, then for each unique value, extract out the right `A` values that match a given `i` value in `b`.

Comment: It works perfectly! Now I have to understand how arrayfun works! Thank you!

Comment: @System - Oh :) `arrayfun` performs a function on each element of an array.  This is basically a `for` loop.  I'll edit my post so that you can see it working with a `for` loop.

Comment: @System - Take a look at my edit.  It explains how `arrayfun` works and how you'd do it if you wanted to use a loop instead.

Answer (score 2):

As [@rayryeng says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32125347/2586922), don't create separate variables; use a [cell array](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html) instead. You can do that with [`accumarray`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) as follows:

First define your data:

```
b = [ 1 2 2 3 4 1 2 1 4 ];
A = 1:numel(b); %// for example
```

Then

```
C = accumarray(b(:), A(:), [], @(x) {x});
```

gives

```
>> C
C = 
    [3x1 double]
    [3x1 double]
    [         4]
    [2x1 double]
>> celldisp(C)
C{1} =
     6
     8
     1
C{2} =
     7
     3
     2
    C{3} =
     4
C{4} =
     5
     9
```

If you want to keep the original order:

```
[bs, ind] = sort(b);
As = A(ind);
C = accumarray(bs(:), As(:), [], @(x) {x});
```

gives

```
>> C
C = 
    [3x1 double]
    [3x1 double]
    [         4]
    [2x1 double]
>> celldisp(C)
C{1} =
     1
     6
     8
C{2} =
     2
     3
     7
C{3} =
     4
C{4} =
     5
     9
```

Comment: Ahh... should have known to use `accumarray`, but yes the `sort` is needed to guarantee the order as the way the numbers are binned together come in random order.  Very good work.